# (Python) Why do I always have to type absolute paths in file functions?

Tags: python, absolute-path

For instance, if I have:
C:\42\main.py
and
C:\42\info.txt
and I want to read info.txt from main.py, I have to input "C:\42\info.txt" instad of just "info.txt".

Is it supposed to be like that?
If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know...however, I would highly recommend against opening paths that way in python, as it removes the ability for that to be portable code.  Rather, make an abstract directory path string.  From there, you can put your C:\42.  Then, when you make your string, concatenate the path_string, and the file_string (info.txt in this case), together.  Then, you can set up your path string to work relative to the OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify paths relative to where your script is.  I do it all the time when writing unittests.

Every python file has a special attribute -- `__file__` -- that stores the path to that file.

```
py_file= os.path.abspath(__file__) # path to main.py
py_dir = os.path.dirname(py_file) # path to the parent dir of main.py
txt_file = os.path.join(py_dir, 'info.txt') # path to info.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

It is supposed to be like that. Relative paths are relative to the process's current working directory, not the directory that your script resides in.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hardcoding it, you can find the script's path using `sys.path[0]`, and either `chdir` to it or use it directly in the filename:

```
os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'info.txt')
```

Comment: sys.path[0] returns the path of the script that was called from command line.  It will not work for scripts imported from a different directory.